# How to return with error if DateTime argument is not a parsable Date?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

**Context**

I have an ASP MVC WebApi controller. My action method has an optional DateTime? parameter:

```
public MyType Query(DateTime? myDate = null)
```

The parameter binding parses dates correctly, however if I sending a request with invalid date, it becomes null, so I can not distinguish between intentionally omitted optional parameters and bad requests.

**Question**

I would like to return to bad requests (invalid date) with error. Can I solve this using the existing parameter binding mechanism, or do I have to declare myDate as string and parse it in the action method code myself?

Comment: imho string is beter option. 
But You can also insted of DateTime? myDate = null use DateTime? myDate = default(DateTime) and if its null than bad request